# Research Assistant badge requirements

Tags: feature-request, badges

I just noticed the new `Research Assistant` badge on SO. The description says that to get it you have to `Edited 50 tag wikis`. Does adding descriptions to existing tag wikis that have no description count towards this? Also does creating tag wiki's count toward this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Yes. An edit includes creating the wiki description.

You need to edit the wiki **body** for it to count towards the badge. **Excerpt** edits don't count.

For more information see [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/59303).

Comment: Thanks. What is an Excerpt edit?

Comment: @BaliC - Tag wikis are split into two parts. The excerpt is what's displayed on the tooltip you get when you hover over the tag. The body is the meat of the wiki which should tell you how to use the tag on the site.