# Are editing excerpt and full tag wiki counted separately for research-assistant badge?

Tags: discussion, tags, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions)
>   [Research Assistant badge requirements](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121517/research-assistant-badge-requirements)

And after editing of excerpt and full wiki of a tag there are two entries in the 'recent activity' log. Are editing excerpt and full wiki of a tag counted as two separate tag edits for getting research-assistant badge?

[Research-assistant](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/1656/research-assistant) badge description states:

> Edited 50 tag wikis.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As reported by Waffles in [his answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/140449) to [New silver badge for editing N tag wikis](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/new-silver-badge-for-editing-n-tag-wikis), "the badge counts distinct tag wikis you edit excluding excerpts."