# Requirements for the Research Assistant badge are misleading in the badge list

Tags: feature-request, badges, documentation, badge-description

The [badge page](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) has this description for the Research Assistant badge:

> edited 50 tag wikis

It does not mention that [editing excerpts does not count](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123498/are-editing-excerpt-and-full-tag-wiki-counted-separately-for-research-assistant). This is just unfair. Please update the documentation.

I think this statement should be longer, documenting that excerpts do not count. I agree this is explained on Meta, but Meta should not be the primary place for getting documentation, or, if so, misleading documentation should be removed from other places.

The [badge tab](https://stackoverflow.com/badges) is the primary means for Stack Overflow users to get information about badges.And this tab contains misleading information that 50 wiki tags edits (= edits of any kind) are sufficient to obtain the badge. Explanations that "can be found somewhere else" are out of scope of this question.

Comment: The [badge FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/list-of-all-badges-with-full-descriptions/68258#68258) does list that requirement. What FAQ are you referring to?

Comment: From that FAQ: *"Edits to tag wiki excerpts do not count"*

Comment: @Bart where do you see this? Most likely, we are talking about different FAQs.

Comment: @Mat, you link to the ordinary Meta Stack Overflow question and not to FAQ. I have just edited my question by adding direct link to the problematic FAQ.

Comment: @AudriusMeškauskas From the FAQ linked by Mat. Not the "FAQ" you've just edited into  your question. Note: Meta questions with the red FAQ tag are also referred to as (Community) FAQs

Comment: @Audrius: I made a rather intrusive edit to your question to remove the term FAQ when you talk about the main badge page, it was really confusing to me. Also I can't see this as a bug, the description is (pedantically) accurate: it doesn't say "50 tag wiki or tag wiki excerpt edits", it says "50 tag wiki edits". So changed to feature request (to update the badge page).

Comment: Thanks, it looks better and more obvious now.