# Tag wiki edits aren't contributing to Research Assistant badge

Tags: support, badges, tag-wiki, edit-badges

Recently, I have done a lot of tag wiki editing. Most of these edits have been accepted. However, only one has contributed to my Research Assistant badge progress!

Extra info which might be unnecessary:

- I have waited more than one UTC day
- They all included edits to the body, not just the excerpt
- Before the edit streak, I had 26 edits. I had 8 accepted edits, and my total increased to 27.

Why is this happening and can anything be done about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, so here's a list of all the tag wikis you've edited. I've bolded the ones that don't count.

- reminders
- screen-capture
- **shortcuts [repeat]**
- font
- **software-recommendation [rejected]**
- stationery-pad
- voice-dictation
- jailbreak
- windows
- ios-5
- **[orphan]**
- **[orphan]**
- **trojan [?]**
- web-browser
- dropbox
- keyboard
- applescript
- email
- wifi
- shortcuts
- apps
- audio
- sync
- system-requirements
- iphone
- macbook-pro
- mountain-lion
- mac
- snow-leopard
- itunes
- **lion [rejected]**
- iod
- safari

The non-bolded ones at up to 27, which matches. The count on your profile doesn't update (at least I don't believe it does) when a tag wiki gets orphaned (the tag is removed). Therefore, the count didn't increment for two of your edits to account for the two that got deleted. Your `[shortcuts]` edit was a repeat, you can't increment twice on the same tag wiki. The only one that caught my eye was the [`[trojan]` tag wiki](https://apple.stackexchange.com/tags/trojan/info). Your suggestion there got approved and it's listed in the [revision history](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/38967/revisions) for the tag, but the actual info page for the tag says that there is no tag wiki for it yet.

Comment: It's interesting that it adds up to 27; the progress bar currently says 29 (I've made three more since it said 27). I suppose the orphaned ones not being counted makes sense, as does the duplicate edit. It still doesn't completely explain it though, as the total *was* at 26, I had 8 accepted edits, and it *was* at 27. Even if the total actually does add up right, it's still unexplained.

Comment: Honestly, if the count is correct, I don't see what needs explained. Perhaps you misread something? Can you create a list of exactly what edits you were referring too? As far as I can see, the count is correct and the only bug lies within the [trojan] tag wiki. The tag wiki counts for the badge are updated immediately once the suggestion is approved (they are for me on SO), so waiting won't change the number.

Comment: font, switching, google-chrome, (shortcuts), and screen-capture. A couple of those were repeats, but I didn't see them even once on your list.

Comment: Also, in regards to trojan: It seems there wasn't an excerpt, so it didn't show up. Interesting.

Comment: @Timothy: [switching] and [google-chrome] say you only edited the excerpt and not the tag wiki, so those two do not count.

Comment: Waffles♦ says that "the badge counts distinct tag wikis you edit excluding excerpts." http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/179339

Comment: @Timothy: ... yes ...so the excerpts don't count towards the Research Assistant badge. That's what "excluding" means.

Comment: D'oh! Misread that about three times! Sorry for the waste of your time, and thanks for the help. :)