# How to track the number of tag wikis I edited?

Tags: support, edits, tag-wiki

I want to see the number of tag wiki that I edited till now. Also I want to see which are accepted and which are rejected with the detail of all those tags. How can I know that?
 Also I want to know the progress for `Research Assisstant` badge.

Comment: Jaguar, why is your profile image a tiger?

Comment: @KevinVermeer I like tigers. If it is against norms then I will change that.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using a tiger as your profile image.  Tigers are awesome!  But I assumed from your username that you were a different sort of cat...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can see the total number of approved tag wiki edits you have on the right hand side of any tag wiki page.  It looks like this:

[image: Yay, badge progress!]

In order to see the other information you want, you'll have to troll through [your "Activity" tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1341006/jaguar?tab=activity&sort=suggestions) on your user profile under the "suggestions" filter.  It looks like this:

[image: the suggestions tab]

There you can click on each suggestion, and look at whether or not it was accepted.  If it was rejected, you will see who rejected it, and what reasons they listed for the rejection.

Comment: I really should edit some tag wikis.  Screenshot fail.

Comment: chrome dev tools is your friend.

Answer (score 2):

With a delay up to a month (or is it two weeks?), you can use the output of [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/about) query *[Top Tag Wiki Editors](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/59615/top-tag-wiki-editors)*<sup>[[1]](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/)</sup> (supposing you have edited more than 10 tag wikis) or write a more targeted SEDE query to see the number of tag wikis edited till now.

This also works *after* you get the current highest level badge (currently [Research Assistant](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/badges/173/research-assistant)) - the progress indicator is absent (it will *not* show 100% or more and the current count) and on sites where the progress indicator is not enabled (like on this site, Meta Stack Overflow).