# Colliding wiki creation causes error

Tags: bug, tag-wiki

I attempted to add a tag wiki excerpt for a tag that did not have one.

While I was carefully crafting the excerpt in the edit page, another inconsiderate user rushed in and quickly created a tag wiki and tag wiki excerpt.

I went to save my changes, expecting to be creating a new tag wiki excerpt, but "Something Bad Happened" and I was redirected to `/error`.

I'm amazed that such a nasty bug has been left unfixed for so long.

It's no wonder that nobody uses tag wikis...

Comment: "*another inconsiderate user rushed in*" - [That hurts my feelings](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/3896).

Comment: Actually, I think nobody uses tag wikis because [they don't serve a useful, clearly defined purpose](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121463/131713).