# Do edits on tag wiki excerpts count toward editing badges?

Tags: discussion, tag-wiki, edit-badges

Do edits on tag wiki excerpts (not the body) count as edits towards Strunk & White and other editing badges?

Comment: Just for context, note that the Research Assistant badge does *not* count edits to tag wiki excerpts. [Reference](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/121484/153008).

Comment: Sorry about re-closing this. It just occurred to me that it's better to just edit the other question to clarify the accepted answer.

Comment: @AnnaLear: now it's OK. I agree it's better to edit the other question and/or its answers, that's why I rollbacked my last edit complaining about absence of the answer in the linked question. Anyway, I have the answer, so I'm happy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [What kind of edits contribute to the editor badges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/442/what-kind-of-edits-contribute-to-the-editor-badges):

> You can also edit tag wikis and their excerpts, which are both counted **separately** as edits.

Comment: That's talking about changing the tags on questions, not edits of tag wiki excerpts.

Comment: @CodyGray: I am awake now, corrected..

Comment: Oh hey! I was just about to post that answer. Unfortunately for you, I'm fresh out of daily votes.