# Issue with the Research Assistant badge progress bar

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, tag-wiki, edit-badges

Recently I did my first tag wiki edit in **StackOverflow**. For this I got the **Tag Editor badge**.

[image: Tag Editor Badge]

But when I checked the badge progress  view. It shows 0 tag wiki edits.

[image: Tag wiki progress]

Is it a bug or am I missing any faq ?

Comment: Cache, it's always cache. Give it a full day, if 24 hours after you got the badge it's still not updated then it's probably a bug.

Comment: How long as it been ?

Comment: @ʞunɥdɐpɐɥd he got the badge [three hours ago](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1104384/midhun-mp?tab=activity&sort=badges).

Comment: Only tag wiki edits count, not tag wiki _excerpt_ edits. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119550/new-silver-badge-for-editing-n-tag-wikis/121484#121484 . So [status-by-design].